# How to copy/export tableau data with the same formatting, instead of crosstab (please see img)

Tags: tableau-api

In my tableau document I have an "emails" pill in the rows, and a condition pill as a text mark. This gives me a list of users (vert) with their conditions listed in line as seen below.
[image]

How can I copy or export or copy the data with the same layout?

I'd like to have a csv / excel document with the data that reads:

```
brett@gmail.com, MS
dfed@gmail.com, COPD
Brielle@gmail.com, Breast Cancer, GU Cancer, Lung Cancer, Melanoma
bsear@gmail.com, Psoriasis & PsA RA
etc...
```

Comment: Does the "worksheet->export->cross tab to excel" work for you? If not what is the formatting you are losing?

Answer (score 0):

Export it to excel, and save it as CSV. Then you'll have a CSV format.